# What's the deal with the soft menu button?

Tags: android

I've published an update to my Android app, and the customers are complaining that the soft menu button (`...`) does not appear anymore. The app goes a long way back, it has a menu. For tablet screens on Android 3+, I apply the Holo theme and the menu appears as an action bar; but on phones, the action bar is not really an option because of space constraints.

I was happy with the soft menu key that Android would provide, except it went away and I can't figure out why. The changes that could affect this since the last release were:

- Increased the target SDK from 14 to 17
- Updated the Android dev tools

Reverting the target SDK back to 14 *by itself* does not help - I've got one complaining customer to install a private build and check. Reverting the dev tools back is hardly an option.

Please, what's the party line on the option menu these days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> except it went away and I can't figure out why

You got rid of the action bar. The overflow affordance appears in the action bar, and then only on devices that lack an off-screen MENU key.

A longer explanation of this, plus some legacy scenarios where there was a `...` affordance in the system bar, can be found in [this old Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

> Please, what's the party line on the option menu these days?

If you are not using the action bar, roll your own "menu" construct.

Comment: Thing is, the previous version had the same setup (Holo on tablets only) - yet the `...` would appear. Also, the previous version used SDK 14 - supposedly, it should not have triggered the legacy behavior.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Regardless, if you are not using the action bar, you should be rolling your own "menu" that is an integrated part of your UI. Or, have a gesture or something that brings back the action bar (so they can press the `...` in there), with it hiding after a period of inactivity.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Call `show()` and `hide()` on `ActionBar`. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing